# MacOS Monetary c++ compilation with Boost Library

Tags: c++, macos, g++, clang, mpfr

I'm compiling some code which uses Boost multiprecision and when I go to call the library with

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
```

Compilation gives the following error:

```
./main.hpp:3:10: fatal error: 'boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Install libmpfr (e.g. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mpfr)

Comment: Already have: 

Warning: mpfr 4.1.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 4.1.0, run:
  brew reinstall mpfr

@sehe

Comment: I misread the error, you need to include the boost headers in your include paths

Comment: you need to install boost and instruct your build manager where is it. With `cmake` it will be `find_package(boost ....)`.

Comment: zsh: unknown file attribute: b

Comment: Anybody got more ideas? @sehe?

Comment: You need to find where the file has been installed: `locate boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp`. If this file is not found, install the package that provides it (probably `boost`). If it is installed but not found by your compiler, set up `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.